Getting started with CMake >= 3.28 and C++20 modules
Can you help me?
Project is quite simple, and I'm already able to build it with some smart shell code scripts, but I want to begin using CMake and C++20 modules but no #include statements.
// file DataLoader.cxx
export module data_loader;
    
export class DataLoader {
public:
    virtual void instanceInfo() const = 0;
};

The class above is just a way of testing virtual functions, while the one below is the actual goal of the project - load a CSV file.
// file FileLoader.cxx
export module file_loader;
    
import data_loader;
import <iostream>;
import <string>;
    
export enum class FileType { csv };
    
export class FileLoader: public DataLoader {
public:
    FileLoader(FileType fileType, std::string filePath);
    FileLoader();
    ~FileLoader();
    void instanceInfo() const override;
private:
    static int count;
    FileType fileType;
    std::string filePath;
};
    
FileLoader::FileLoader(FileType fileType, std::string filePath):
    fileType(fileType), filePath(filePath) {
    ++count;
}
    
FileLoader::FileLoader() { ++count; }
    
FileLoader::~FileLoader() { --count; }
    
int FileLoader::count = 0;
    
export void FileLoader::instanceInfo() const {
    std::cout << "File #" << count;
    if (filePath.length())
        std::cout << " (" << filePath << ")";
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

And then building a main file for using the aforementioned classes.
// file main.cxx
import file_loader;
import <memory>;

using namespace std;

int main() {
    unique_ptr<FileLoader> fl(new FileLoader());
    fl->instanceInfo();

    unique_ptr<FileLoader> fl1(new FileLoader(FileType::csv, "test.csv"));
    fl1->instanceInfo();
}

The goal is also to start using CMake, since I've been writing shell code to compile my C++20 with no #includes.
// file CMakeLists.txt

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.28)
project(cpp-data-viz LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)

add_library(data_loader)
target_sources(data_loader PUBLIC
    FILE_SET CXX_MODULES
        FILES
            DataLoader.cxx)

add_library(file_loader)
target_sources(file_loader PUBLIC
    FILE_SET CXX_MODULES
        FILES
            FileLoader.cxx)

add_executable(main main.cxx)
target_link_libraries(main file_loader data_loader)`

But I get the error messages below:
cmake -GNinja ..

-- Configuring done (0.0s)
CMake Error in CMakeLists.txt:
  The target named "data_loader" has C++ sources that may use modules, but
  the compiler does not provide a way to discover the import graph
  dependencies.  See the cmake-cxxmodules(7) manual for details.  Use the
  CMAKE_CXX_SCAN_FOR_MODULES variable to enable or disable scanning.


CMake Error in CMakeLists.txt:
  The target named "file_loader" has C++ sources that may use modules, but
  the compiler does not provide a way to discover the import graph
  dependencies.  See the cmake-cxxmodules(7) manual for details.  Use the
  CMAKE_CXX_SCAN_FOR_MODULES variable to enable or disable scanning.


-- Generating done (0.0s)
CMake Generate step failed.  Build files cannot be regenerated correctly.`

VERSIONS:
g++ version 11.4.0
cmake version 3.29.3
ninja version 1.12.1

I just want to be able to compile and run C++20 modules with CMake, but it's kind of tricky. I probably should just use #includes and give up, I guess ???

"give up" is not in my dictionary and shouldn’t be in yours either. I’ll write an answer.

You need a compiler implementing p1689, for gcc this is version 14 or higher. See https://www.kitware.com/import-cmake-the-experiment-is-over/

Compilers which CMake natively supports module dependency scanning include:

GCC 14 and newer. 
LLVM/Clang 16.0 and newer. 
MSVC toolset 14.34 and newer.

Hence to get this feature seamlessly, upgrade your compiler.

If something doesn't work as expected, check the documentation [cmake.org] to know what went wrong.

Thank you guys - I'm still intalling everything but I guess I made a little bit of confusion between gcc's C++20 support and gcc's C++20 modules dependency support and which version is really needed.

Well, I just can't build it, even if I managed to correctly generate the ninja.build file with cmake. Guess I'll just study CMake from Scratch.

Have you made all the necessary installations that support this feature?

Besides not meeting the tooling requirements, as pointed out by the other answer, your code also has a bunch of problems:

Header units are not supported by CMake. Don't try to use the standard library via header units. Either use the modularized C++ standard library from C++23 (which is currently not supported with gcc and has only partial support on Clang 17) or use standard library headers from the global module fragment.
You're missing a dependency from FileLoader to DataLoader. With modules, it is even more crucial than with headers to model your dependencies correctly. Add a target_link_libraries(file_loader PUBLIC data_loader) to your CMakeLists.txt.
export void FileLoader::instanceInfo() const is invalid syntax. The export goes on the class declaration only, not on the individual member functions.

With these changes in place, your example works fine on both Clang and gcc. You can try it out in Compiler Explorer.
